# How to Uninstall Xen

Tags: ubuntu, xen

I have recently installed Xen on a Server, and now I'm unable to remote access the server, and the server's eth0 doesn't get configured even when I run `/etc/init.d/networking restart`.

I want to now uninstall Xen **completely** from my server. How do I go about doing that? I can't find any uninstall guides online. Also, I have to do it from command line, not GUI interface. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the source code:

```
make uninstall
```

Answer (score 0):

apt-get autoremove [packagename]

Answer (score -1):

If you're just starting with Xen, try to install it from Ubutnu repositories, not from source. Then when you know more about it, a custom install from source could be better for your requirements.

apt-cache search xen

find the packages that you want and then:

sudo apt-get install xen_package_name_that_you_found

Comment: the question was how to uninstall xen, not install more of it

Comment: I know, but he(or she) said that after installing Xen, he can't make it work and now he want to uninstall. The uninstall question was already perfectly answered, so I went further and tried to help on the original problem. We're not machines, we can answer more than the exact question, it isn't so difficult to understand, or out of place, don't you think?